# Where can I find the equivalent of detailed Heroku logs on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, error-handling, aws-opsworks

I have a ruby application that I used to deploy and run on Heroku, but recently switched to AWS by using Opsworks. The application is running just fine, but I had a question about detailed error logs.

On Heroku, I could just type `heroku logs` and get detailed logs that would help me troubleshoot errors I saw in my application. However, I can't quite find the equivalent in AWS. I've tried going into my ec2 instance and into `/var/log/` to find the detailed logs I need. The closest thing I found was going into the /ngninx folder and viewing the `[app_name].com.acess.log` file. I get logs, but they are not nearly as detailed as what I saw on Heroku.

As a result, troubleshooting is really difficult so far on AWS. Does anyone know of a location to some detailed logs or a way to enable some if they do not exist by default?

Any insight would be really helpful : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the log on AWS OpsWorks by doing something like this :

```
sudo su deploy
cd /srv/www/[app_name]/shared/log/
```

There you can find the logs, for example probably a `production.log` or `unicorn.stdout.log`

Comment: Thanks! Trying to navigate to the shared folder and don't seem to have permission to access. I am getting the following:                                         -bash: cd: shared: Permission denied                                                               Any way to set my own permissions or override the access?

Comment: Solved! just typed sudo su to change over to root user and was able to navigate everywhere. The file was close, it turned out to be     *unicorn.stdout.log*  Thanks so much! : )